# What is the advantage of saving `.npz` files instead of `.npy` in python, regarding speed, memory and look-up?

Tags: python, numpy, serialization, archive, npz-file

The python documentation for the `numpy.savez` which saves an `.npz` file is:

> The .npz file format is a zipped archive of files named after the variables they contain. The archive is not compressed and each file in the archive contains one variable in .npy format. [...]
>
> When opening the saved .npz file with load a NpzFile object is
>   returned. This is a dictionary-like object which can be queried for
>   its list of arrays (with the .files attribute), and for the arrays
>   themselves.

My question is: what is the point of `numpy.savez`?

Is it just a more elegant version (shorter command) to save multiple arrays, or is there a speed-up in the saving/reading process? Does it occupy less memory?

Comment: What's the point of file archives?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

There are two parts of explanation for answering your question.

#### I. NPY vs. NPZ

As we already read from the doc, the `.npy` format is:

> the standard binary file format in NumPy for persisting a ***single*** arbitrary NumPy array on disk. ... The format is designed to be as simple as possible while achieving its limited goals. ([sources](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lib.format.html#npy-format))

And `.npz` is only a

> simple way to combine ***multiple*** arrays into a single file, one can use ZipFile to contain multiple “`.npy`” files. We recommend using the file extension “`.npz`” for these archives. ([sources](https://numpy.org/neps/nep-0001-npy-format.html#conventions))

So, `.npz` is just a ZipFile containing multiple “`.npy`” files. And this ZipFile can be *either compressed (by using `np.savez_compressed`) or uncompressed (by using `np.savez`)*.

It's similar to [tarball archive file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)) in Unix-like system, where a tarball file can be just an uncompressed archive file which containing other files or a compressed archive file by combining with various compression programs (`gzip`, `bzip2`, etc.)

#### II. Different APIs for binary serialization

And Numpy also provides [different APIs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.io.html#numpy-binary-files-npy-npz) to produce these binary file output:

- `np.save` ---> Save an array to a binary file in NumPy `.npy` format
- `np.savez` --> Save several arrays into a single file in *uncompressed* `.npz` format
- `np.savez_compressed` --> Save several arrays into a single file in *compressed* `.npz` format
- `np.load` --> Load arrays or pickled objects from `.npy`, `.npz` or pickled files

If we skim the source code of Numpy, [under the hood](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.17.0/numpy/lib/npyio.py#L707):

```py
def _savez(file, args, kwds, compress, allow_pickle=True, pickle_kwargs=None):
    ...
    if compress:
        compression = zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED
    else:
        compression = zipfile.ZIP_STORED
    ...


def savez(file, *args, **kwds):
    _savez(file, args, kwds, False)


def savez_compressed(file, *args, **kwds):
    _savez(file, args, kwds, True)
```

---

Then back to the question:

- If only use `np.save`, there is no more compression on top of the `.npy` format, only just a single archive file for the convenience of managing multiple related files.
- If use `np.savez_compressed`, then of course less memory on disk because of more CPU time to do the compression job (i.e. a bit slower).

Comment: why do I need torch when load npz sometimes???

Answer (score 10):

The main advantage is that the arrays are lazy loaded.  That is, if you have an `npz` file with 100 arrays you can load the file without actually loading any of the data.  If you request a single array, only the data for that array is loaded.

A downside to `npz` files is they can't be memory mapped (using `load(<file>, mmap_mode='r')`), so for large arrays they may not be the best choice.  For data where the arrays have a common shape I'd suggest taking a look at [structured arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.rec.html).  These can be memory mapped, allow accessing data with dict-like syntax (i.e., `arr['field']`), and are very efficient memory wise.

Comment: Are they compressed or not though? do they occupy less memory when you save them?

Comment: @SuperCiocia, No, from the docs you've included: "The archive is not compressed".

Comment: Yeah exactly, hence why i don't see the point. The memory of npz is the same as npy then no?

Comment: Saving space on disk isn't the point.  The lazy loading used will speed up loading and save space in ram.

Comment: But what's the difference between saving my 100 arrays as 100 .npy arrays and only loading the one I want, and saving them as 1 .npz file and requesting a single of the those arrays?

Comment: @SuperCiocia did you figure out an answer to your above question? I'm pondering this as well.

Comment: No, sorry. Let me know if you do!

Comment: performing operations on structured arrays were always a pain for me. forget why.

Comment: @SuperCiocia

It can look neater, and be more convenient, to have a single `.npz` file. On the other hand, having multiple `.npy` files allows you to cut-and-paste particular versions of a variable, without affecting the other variables stored in the other `.npy` files. Space-wise on disk, the two approaches will be similar (unless a very large number of very small files).

Comment: @SuperCiocia adding to the comment from @Eureka, I wanted to add that the `.npz`-format has basically 2 advantages over single files. First: All stored sub-arrays are indexed in the header, which makes random read on multiple arrays faster than having to query the filesystem index for each file. Second as @Eureka said, if you have a lot of small files, moving them or batch updating will be a lot faster. However, if you only always need a single array from certain context or want to do a high amount of individual updates which cannot be batched, you're better off using single files.